# DateTime conversion from Utc to Local in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#

I have a function which among other things does a conversion from Utc to Local and vice-versa.
The problem is that when I run it on a PC with Win 7 it works OK, but when I run it on a PC with Vista the conversion goes wrong.

ex: My current time zone is +2 UTC

MyCurrentTime is set to 27.09.2012, 19:00 and the DateTimeKind is Unspecified.

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(MyCurrentTime,DateTimeKind.Utc);  
DateTime localTime = new DateTime();                             
localTime = utcTime.Date.ToLocalTime();
```

The output on Win 7 is 27.09.2012, 17:00

The output on Vista is 27.09.2012, 04:00

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the time zone settings on both machines the same?

Comment: Do they have same DST settings? What is the exact time zone (not just the offset from UTC) on both machines?

Comment: "Yes, they are the same" - I bet they're not!

Comment: What is DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow on both machines? (it *sounds* like something is set incorrectly)

Comment: You would lose that bet. "(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest" on both machines.

Comment: The code run is identical on both machines. It was unit tested with the same unit test on both machines, and while one was OK, the other was wrong. I suspect that this could be a Windows thing, but I'm looking for other opinions.

Comment: Did you try something like [`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.tolocaltime.aspx)

Comment: Did you ask a colleague to take a look? Seems like it's the kind of obvious and easy stuff one can spend hours on it unable to spot it even if it's right here.

Comment: again, what are your DST settings? If you open the TimeZone editor in Win7, and toggle DST checkbox, you will see that local time changes by 1 hour which is consistent with your issue.

Comment: DST is +1. However, I think the Win 7 machine is working fine.

Comment: Check whether you are seeing the same issue with DatetimeOffset?

Comment: Yes, the DST is also the same. It seems that the TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime could work. I will update the situation after I will test it on both machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was the one suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/570150/v4vendetta.

Both the Win 7 and Vista machines "agreed" on the correct time.

```
localTime= TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(utcTime);
```

Thanks a lot!